# EJB Timer Service error

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, timer, ejb

I'm trying to use the EJB timer service, I have a class named TimerBean which carries the methods to schedule a timer and handle the timeout, this implements TimerBeanRemote an interface class.

In another session bean I have the following:

```
TimerBeanRemote service = (TimerBeanRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("TimerBean/remote");
```

When I try to run it on the server I get the error:

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'TimerBean/remote' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TimerBean]

Any ideas as to why it can't find it? Thanks!

Comment: Which App Server are you using? There seems to be a problem with your JNDI name. You can confirm the correct name in Admin console or Server log at the start up time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using glassfish. Is there a link to some tutorial which shows me how to set up this JNDI stuff? Sorry new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from your comments -if you are trying to access `TimerBeanRemote` within the same container then you can inject the `@Remote` ejb in your servlet or JSF Backing Bean else you can locate your EJB through a JNDI lookup.

Suppose your TimerBean is: `com.mypackage.timer.TimerBeanRemote` 
then as per explanation above you can either inject or lookup:

1. Injection

   `public class MyServlet ...{


   @EJB

   com.mypackage.timer.TimerBeanRemote timerBean;

   }`
2. JNDI lookup:

`Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

    String[] serverDetails = server.split(":");

    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", MyHost);

    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", MyPort);`

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);<br>
TimerBeanRemote timerBean = (TimerBeanRemote)ic.lookup("com.mypackage.timer.TimerBeanRemote");
```

You can read the following articles for further details:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Session5.html

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/3-ejb-30-timer-services-an-overview-1.html